# Getting the hashtags from a tweet in C

Tags: c, string

Hi guys I have a question about string manipulation in C.

I was given a file and got the tweet from it and I am asked to get the hashtags from the string and put in into avl tree so all of my avl functions are fine but scanning the string part is a bit problematic.

My tweet sample is `hello buddies #happy`

Here is the code:

```
void read_tweet_data(avl_tree *t, char name[]) {
    FILE *data;
    data = fopen(name, "r");
    char eof, temp[140], *temp2;
    char *has, *myc;
    int i;
    while (fgets(temp, 140, data) != EOF) {
        //puts(temp);
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {
            //Dont know what I should put there.
        }
    }
}
```

I need to scan the hashtags without the '#'s in it and I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` in a loop, use `for (i = 0 ; temp[i] != '\0' ; ++i)`. The `strlen()` function computes the length by iterating through the characters until it finds the `'\0'` which marks the end of the string, using `strlen()` like you did is very inefficient.

Comment: _//Dont know what I should put there._ - `if (temp[i] == '#') { /* skip this character by advancing i */; /* while (temp[i] != '\0' && temp[i] != ' ') /* store temp[i] somewhere and advance i */;`

Comment: Make the buffer at least `142` characters to accommodate for the `140` characters in the message, the `'\n'` and the null terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Why `\n`? Isn't 141 sufficient?

Comment: @rootkea: because `fgets()` stores the `'\n'` at the end of the buffer.  If the buffer is too short, it leaves it in the input stream, which is not appropriate either.

Comment: (I've reverted the title to the original; "Answered string" isn't a useful title. Users can see that the problem was solved, because an answer has been accepted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you write:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {
    //Dont know what I should put there.
}
```

Others have pointed out that you shouldn't use `strlen` as a loop condition; use `temp[i] != '\0'` instead. The real problem is that you probably don't want to extract the hashtags in a single loop.

You are looking for a certain pattern and you don't know up front how many hits you will get. After you have found one occurrence, you look again in the rest of the string.

Therefore, it may be a good idea to write a function that processes a tweet one hashtag at a time. This function needs a state variable, so it knows where it left off last time it was called.

The resulting hashtag must be stored somewhere. Some functions, for example `strtok`, modify the original string to generate null-terminated substrings without copying the data. That can't be done here, because hashtags may run into each other `#like#this` and overwiting the second hash with a null character will skip the hash tag `this`. So the function is passed a char buffer, which can be filled. The buffer size is passed, too, so that the buffer will not be overwritten. The string in the buffer is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

A [hashtag](https://www.hashtags.org/platforms/twitter/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/) is a hash sign that is immediately followed by unaccented latin characters, numbers and an underscore. The first character afer the hash sign may not be a number.

Putting all this together:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_valid(int c, int num_allowed)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') return 1;
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') return 1;
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return num_allowed;
    if (c == '_') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int hashtag(char **p, char buf[], size_t max)
{
    char *q;

    if (*p == NULL || **p == '\0') return 0;

    q = strchr(*p, '#');
    while (q && is_valid(q[1], 0) == 0) {
        q = strchr(q + 1, '#');
    }

    if (q) {
        size_t n = 0;

        q++;                    // skip hash sign

        while (n + 1 < max && is_valid(*q, 1)) {
            buf[n++] = *q++;
        }

        if (max) buf[n] = '\0'; // terminate buffer
        *p = q;                 // remember position

        return 1;               // hashtag found
    }

    return 0;                   // nothing found
}
```

And an example how to use the function:

```
int main()
{
    char *tweet = "#amith7951 https://t.co/eoW5q7V2Fh #net "
                  "#ajax #asp #cprogramming #sql "
                  "### ###happy#new#2016 #";

    char *p = tweet;            // state variable for hashtag function
    char tag[32];               // char buffer to store hashtag in
    int n = 0;

    while (hashtag(&p, tag, sizeof(tag))) {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", n++, tag);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting function may look long, but it the calling code is straightforward. The function also makes heavy use of pointers. You could use array indices, but because `strchr` (and many othzer library functions)  use pointers anyway, it makes sense to use pointers throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `#` character in `for` loop and if match found then copy the string starting from next character till `\0` or another `#` occurs.

If another `#` character occurs then again copy the string starting from next character till `\0` or another `#` occurs to retrieve the second hash tag.

And as pointed in another comment use `len = strlen()` and then use this `len` variable in for loop to avoid the function overhead for each `for` iteration

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the `#` with `strchr()` like this

```
char *hashtag = strchr(temp, '#');
if (hashtag != NULL)
    hashtag += 1;
```

and you can replace the next white space with `nul`, now `hashtag` points to the "*hashtag*" but the one in the `temp` array, if you need to copy you can use `strdup()` or any non POSIX variant that is likely available on your system if it's not POSIX compliant.

Also, don't compare `fgets()` return value to `EOF`, because `fgets()` returns a pointer, the fact that you don't mention your compiler warning you about it means that you might have compiler warnings turned off, the right way would be

```
char line[1024]; // More if lines can be longer
char *hashtag;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), data) != NULL)
{
     char *end;
     hashtag = line;
     while ((hashtag != NULL) && ((hashtag = strchr(hashtag, '#')) != NULL))
     {
         if (hashtag == NULL)
             continue;
         end = strpbrk(hashtag, "\n ");
         if (end != NULL)
             *end = '\0';
         hashtag += 1;
         // Copy hashtag here
         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", hashtag); // Print it to see
         // Continue to the next character
         hashtag = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine if there's only a single hashtag in the string, but if there are multiple, since `temp` doesn't change between loops this isn't going to let you find them iteratively.

Comment: thank you so much this just gives the exact answer!!